# joomla slider image taking different URL

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I am new in joomla. And I got suddenly to fix the bug in joomla. We have one host with two domains name.

1. www.test1.com
2. www.test2.com

test1.com is working fine but test2.com is my original one now which is created newly.
Here on home page I have **slider Code7 Responsive Slider** on slider images the url is taking test1.com/images/image.png instead of test2.com/images/image.png.

Please let me know where i need to change for that to fix the problem.
version joomla3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didnt know the module, but I downloaded it to see what it does. It's located in `/modules/mod_reslider/` and the file that loads the images is `helper.php`. It appears that your `JURI::root()` loads the wrong url from `/configuration.php` in your site root.

This is usually when the `$live_site` variable is set.

Solution: Search and replace every occurrence of `JURI::root()` to `"http://www.test2.com"` in `/modules/mod_reslider/helper.php` or change your `/configuration.php`.

Good luck!

Comment: I would recommend changing the `$live_site` in your configuration.php file rather than replacing `JURI::root()` with your URL as it's bad practice